# node.js native module SSL

Tags: node.js, abi

on node documentation it is written ([link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules)) this:

*Native Node.js modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron has a different application binary interface (ABI) from a given Node.js binary (due to differences such as using Chromium's BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL), the native modules you use will need to be recompiled for Electron. Otherwise, you will get the following class of error when you try to run your app:*

Anyone can help me to understand why is necessary to involve SSL to send data from pieces of code that are compiled and integrated on the same package?

Thank you

I send this for my knowledge.

---

It's difficult to clarify this point. In node documentation it's expressly written that you can't compile c++ due to the different ABI applied.
That is: you want to link your native code in node environment ?
Ok you have to follow my rules..

For me these rules shoul be (as example): R1:the first argument must be passed in Reg1, R2: ... etc.

When you link to libraries in C or C++ the passing parameters and the relative rules are defined in the ABI. I never heard of SSL in these cases.
Here intead seems completely different the question. Where the SSL takes part in this business?
Now I hope to be clear.

Comment: Where did it say what you are asking about?

Comment: SSL **isn't** involved. The ABIs are just different shapes because Electron has differences to Node.js. The use of OpenSSL/BoringSSL is just one of those differences.

Comment: @user3427419 follow the (link) in the text

Comment: @Quentin, are you saying that the ssl is involved in the packaging phase? So all the parts of the code must have a signature based on the identical algorithm...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Quentin, I'm sorry. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The document says (emphasis mine) "due to differences **such as** using Chromium's BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL".

It's just saying OpenSSL vs BoringSSL is one of the differences, and implies there are likely to be more (and it's not worth anyone's time to enumerate them there in the document) that make it necessary to rebuild native modules against Electron.

It doesn't say SSL is involved in *everything* about the ABI; to answer "Where the SSL takes part in this business?", I'd say "when you use something that ends up using SSL".

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake.